# Unable to use C++20 standard modules with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, c++-modules

I'm trying to use modules from C++20.
Everything works properly with my own modules; I can create and use them normally.

However, if I want to import standard modules (std.core, std.regex, etc), I get the error below, and cannot find anything similar on internet:

> E3373    IFC file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.31.31103\ifc\x64/Debug/std.core.ifc"
> has unsupported version 0.41

Comment: Are you compiling your code [as required for importing the MSVC non-standard standard library module imports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170)?

Comment: Yes, /std:c++latest and /experimental:module are both enabled.

Comment: I also tried to reinstall the modules extension from the Visual Studio Installer but it had no effect at all.

Comment: "*Yes, /std:c++latest and /experimental:module are both enabled.*" That's to enable the modules feature. To be able to include the non-standard MSVC standard library modules, you have to do other things too.

Comment: And yes /MD and /EHsc are enabled too, but this does not seem to be the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Also tried to change the version of the file with the help of the IFC format specifications sheet, but it looks like no version from 0.25 to 0.42 works.

Comment: I was able to use std.core after setting the two settings. Try to create a new project and  use :

`import std.core;

int main(){ std::cout << "hello";
} `

Comment: Still get the same error. I guess I will wait for an update or try the preview version.

Comment: Since we are unable to reproduce the problem, it will be better to provide a minimal sample. Try to repair or reinstall the VS.

Comment: Minxin Yu provided the example I used. I already entirely reinstalled Visual Studio, both Preview and Community versions.

Comment: For your reference: [C++ modules compilation error](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/C-modules-compilation:-error-C3474-co/1130956)